# csv file giving undefined reading

Tags: javascript, string, callback, undefined

I am reading from a csv file. I am receiving the call back as collection of objects.
Each object contains 12 items eg: received callback result is:

I am getting every value and being able to do calculations on them.
But when I check particularly batting_innings I get undefined error.

If you see batting_innings is surrounded by "".

I need batting_innings value as well.

Code is like this

```
function readTextFile(file,callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    var fileContent;

    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                fileContent =csvJSON(allText);
                callback(fileContent);
            }
        }
    }

    rawFile.send(null);
}

//var csv is the CSV file with headers
function csvJSON(csv) {
    var lines=csv.split("\n");
    var result = [];
    var headers=lines[0].split(",");

    for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++) {
        var obj = {};
        var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

        for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++) {
            obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }

        result.push(obj);
    }

    console.log(result[1]);  
    return result; //JavaScript object
}

readTextFile('main.csv', function(data) {
    // operations here
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the csv content in plain text?

Comment: How are you reading the file? Can you give an example of the file you're reading? You haven't given us enough information. Edit your question to include the required information.

Comment: Need to see the code you're using to read and parse the file.

Comment: The "CSV content in plain text" is not CSV content. You need to post the RAW CSV content. Don't format it in any way.

Comment: you need a "proper" csv reader. splitting by lines then by comma only handle "ideal" situations. your csv reader does not read fully qualified csv

Comment: The value may be undefined because it contains \r
"batting_score,wickets,runs_conceded,catches,stumps,opposition,ground,date,match_result,result_margin,toss,batting_innings\r\n0,-,-,0,0,v Pakistan,Gujranwala,18-Dec-89,lost,7 runs,won,2nd\r\n